# How do I do decimal formatting in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, calculator

Pretty new to the whole iPhone development scene. I am just practicing, trying to create a basic calculator, I can add simple numbers but I'd like to support decimal places.

Heres my code so far:

```
    - (IBAction) calculate
{
    double number1 = ([textField.text doubleValue]);
    double answer = number1+([textField2.text doubleValue]);
    label.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2.f", answer];

}

- (IBAction) clear
{
        textField.text = @"";
        textField2.text = @"";
        label.text = @"";

}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: @Seva how to support decimal places.

Comment: You'll want to do the following to avoid a memory leak: `label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.f", answer];`. Just thought I'd point that out. :)

Comment: So uh, is this a C question, or one related to iOS? You're not really asking a question here. What are you stuck on?

Comment: And right now it does not? Seems like the math is already floating point. If you're not getting the digits after the decimal point on output, play with the `%2.f` format specifier. Start with plain %f.

Comment: By the way, no need for parentheses in `double answer = number1+([textField2.text doubleValue]);`.  That can be written as `double answer = number1+[textField2.text doubleValue];`.

Comment: I'd also not set your text to an empty string.  Nil will work just fine--and you won't be using `autorelease` objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your format might be wrong. What is the output you're expecting, and what are you getting?

If I'm guessing correctly, you may want to try this:

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%5.2f", answer];
```

where the 5 means total digits (in terms of padding for alignment), and the 2 means 2 decimal places.

EDIT: avoiding memory leak, as mentioned in donkim's comment!

Comment: Never used this website before, but its amazing! Such a quick answer. Cheers Dave, just what I'm looking for.

Comment: No problem, Skene. A vote up and an accepted answer (green tick) would make it more than worthwhile! :) It will also give you more reputation points, and make people more likely to help you in the future. Enjoy!